# Params from Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, routes, react-router

I want the pathvalue to be mapped from JSON. The pathvalue will have the page name which needs to load from JSON.

```
        <Switch>
            <Route
            render={({ location }) => {
            const {pathname} = location;
            const pathvalue = {pathname}

            return (
            <>  
            <div>
            </div>


            <div className="container">
            {                   
                data.pathvalue.map((rows, i) => { //Instead of telling the page name, I stored the page name in pathvalue const. Is it possible?
                    return (
                        <div key={i} className="row">                           
                            {rows.row.map((component, i) => {
```

Comment: How did you import your react router components?

Comment: I am not using pathname anywhere.

Comment: I believe `<Router />` only takes a single child node. Have you tried removing the `<nav />` component and only keeping the `<Switch />`?

Comment: <div>
                  {pathname} //This prints the pathname in Nav component
                </div>

Comment: You could always just wrap the component using withRouter

Comment: @WebbH, I tried that and updated the code. Still need help.

Comment: @wentjun, instead of importing, I merged nav and app component and updated the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Router />` component only takes a single child component. [You can see it in the documentation here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/children-node)

```
export default function Nav() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          render={({ location }) => {
            const { pathname } = location;
            return <div>{pathname}</div>;
          }}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

You can then either include the `<nav />` component outside the `<Router />` component, or include a single `<div />` inside with both included.